# Нестандартная сериализация/десериализация при помощи newtonsoft json

Tags: c#, json, serialize

Есть следующие классы:

```
public sealed class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Schema Extensions { get; set; }  
}

public sealed class UserProperty
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public sealed class Schema
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<UserProperty> Properties { get; set; } 
}
```

Задается вот так:

```
 var user = new User
 {
    Id = 1,
    Extensions = new Schema
    {
      Name = "urn:scim:schemas:custom:1.0",
      Properties = new List<UserProperty> { new UserProperty { Id = "A", Value = 1} }

    }
 };
```

Необходимо получить json следующего вида:

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "urn:scim:schemas:custom:1.0": {
     "A": 1
  }
}
```

Как это можно сделать при помощи библиотеки newtonsoft? И соответственно потом десериализовать в структуры, описанные выше?

Comment: У вас JSON не соответствует объектной модели. В модели у `User` есть свойство `Extensions`, а в json-объекте есть свойство под названием `"urn:scim:schemas:custom:1.0"`. Так что делайте вручную.

Comment: Спасибо, капитан очевидность!

Comment: Ну, ваш вопрос в стиле «мне надо из 1, 2, 3 получить _папа_, _мама_, _рок-н-ролл_, как?»

Comment: Смотрите в сторону ItemConverterType. вот тут есть пример http://stackoverflow.com/a/14376417/1558147  я не готов адаптировать его под вашу задачу и написать полноценный ответ

Comment: Так же можете посмотреть в сторону `JsonConverter`

Comment: @DenisZibzeev По вашему примеру и классам совершенно неясно, как вы собираетесь отделяться обычные свойства от относящихся к "схеме".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужен `JsonExtensionDataAttribute`. Но тут есть ограничение - насколько я понимаю, он может быть только типа, реализующего `IDictionary<string, JToken>`.

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо:-)